# Organising Audiobook Folders with Banshee

Tags: music, banshee

So Banshee has me really confused.  I have 2 folders - Music and Audiobooks which are empty.  I move some m4b audiobooks into the Audiobooks folder and I have unchecked that it should move them to the Library. (If its checked, it moves them into the Music folder instead of the audiobooks one) but I do have checked that it should keep the files and folders organised.  When I do a refresh it loads the audiobooks into the music library AGAIN. Huh?  Even worse, it doesnt reorganised filenames or folders in the Audiobooks folder.  It has no effect. They are all named exactly the same as they were before and there is no folder structure.  All I want is properly organised Music and Audiobook collections.  I've been trying to get it done for the last 3 days with Rhythmbox and Amarok and now Banshee with zero luck.  OMG This shouldn't be that hard! Don't other Ubuntu users have collections of Music and Audiobooks?

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this with Banshee 2.6.2 (Ubuntu 14.04): twenty audio books already arranged in their own folders under ~/Audiobooks, and my music in ~/Music. The copy files to media folder option unchecked.

After doing the import into the Music library, select each audiobook in the library browser and then drag it to the Audiobooks source in the left panel.  That moves them from the Music source to Audiobooks (just the library view, not the files).

My audio books were ripped from CD, and each disc was showing its own icon in the Audiobooks library.  These can be merged in the Audiobooks library view by shift or ctrl selecting all of the entries belonging to the same book, then right click and select Merge Discs...